# extract a specific table from wikipedia in R

Tags: r

I want to extract the 20th table from a Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/...

I now use this code, but it only extracts the first heading table.

```
the_url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/..."
tb <- the_url %>% read_html() %>% 
  html_node("table") %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

What should I do to get the specific one? Thank you!!

Comment: Try `html_node(xpath = "//table[20]")` instead of plain `html_node("table")`. As of right now, it is the 20th table in that html. Note that its position  might change in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have a specific table you want to **scrape** you can identify in in the html_node() call by using the xpath of the webpage element:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

the_url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup"

the_url %>%
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath='/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/table[20]') %>% 
  html_table(fill=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of indexing where table position could move, you could anchor according to relationship to element with id prize_money. Return just a single node for efficiency. Avoid longer xpaths as they can be fragile.

```
library(rvest)

table <- read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup#Prize_money') %>% 
  html_node(xpath = "//*[@id='Prize_money']/parent::h4/following-sibling::table[1]") %>% 
  html_table(fill = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
library(rvest)

webpage <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup")

tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")

tbls_ls <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[3:4] %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)

str(tbls_ls)
```